# How do I keep speech-to-text active in Gboard even during silences?

Tags: gboard, voice-typing

I often use Gboard's speech-to-text to do voice typing. However, every time I pause speaking for a few seconds, I have to reactivate this feature by clicking the microphone on the keyboard.

How do I keep it active for longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6, one has to double tap on the microphone button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been pressing and holding the voice button on gboard and letting go when I'm done speaking. It works flawlessly for me this way. Pixel 7.

I think it even goes into offline mode when you do this, so no lag.